# How to compare columns in Pandas while matching multiple different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm building a machine learning software to segment pages of large packages of data. I'm trying to do some analysis of the model by automating the process of verifying predicted output against the target output with labels. To do this, I've created a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
page_num    file    predicted    label
--------------------------------------
1           file1       0          0
1           file1       0          0
2           file1       0          0
2           file1       0          0
2           file1       0          0
3           file1       1          1
3           file1       1          1
3           file1       1          1
1           file2       0          0
1           file2       0          0
1           file2       0          0
2           file2       2          2
2           file2       2          2
...
n           filen       0          0
```

There are other columns too that I left out for brevity (total of 13 columns, not including index). I'm relatively new to pandas, but I'm basically looking to get the dataframe to look like this:

```
page_num    file    predicted    label
--------------------------------------
1           file1       0          0
2           file1       0          0
3           file1       1          1
1           file2       0          0
2           file2       2          2
...
n           filen       0          0
```

So I can verify that the values in `predicted == label` for each `page` in each `file`.

I've tried a couple of things:

First, I tried `df[df.groupby(['file', 'page_num'])]`, but that yielded the error 'ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 489 to array axis with dimension 13'.

I checked `df.groupby(['file', 'page_num']).groups` and noted that the groups are what I want: files and their pages. But I can't use the DataFrame `where` function, and I don't think `apply` is what I want either.

I've also tried to just iterate through the groups and check the dataframe, but I get a lot of `False` outcomes. The Jupyter notebook output looks like:

```
for group in df.groupby(['file', 'page_num']).groups:
    df[df.file == group[0], df.page_num == group[1]].reset_index(drop=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b34f0ce41321> in <module>
      1 for group in df.groupby(['file', 'page_num']).groups:
----> 2     temp_df = df[df.file == group[0], df.page_num == group[1]].reset_index(drop=True)
      3     print(temp_df.label)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\base\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\base\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
   2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(0           True
1           True
2           True
3           True
4           True
5           True
6           True
7           True
8           True
9           True
10          True
11          True
12          True
13          True
14          True
15          True
16          True
17          True
18          True
19          True
20          True
21          True
22          True
23          True
24          True
25          True
26          True
27          True
28          True
29          True
           ...  
2028635    False
2028636    False
2028637    False
2028638    False
2028639    False
2028640    False
2028641    False
2028642    False
2028643    False
2028644    False
2028645    False
2028646    False
2028647    False
2028648    False
2028649    False
2028650    False
2028651    False
2028652    False
2028653    False
2028654    False
2028655    False
2028656    False
2028657    False
2028658    False
2028659    False
2028660    False
2028661    False
2028662    False
2028663    False
2028664    False
Name: file, Length: 2028665, dtype: bool, 0           True
1           True
2           True
3           True
4           True
5           True
6           True
7           True
8           True
9           True
10          True
11          True
12          True
13          True
14          True
15          True
16          True
17          True
18          True
19          True
20          True
21          True
22          True
23          True
24          True
25          True
26          True
27          True
28          True
29          True
           ...  
2028635    False
2028636    False
2028637    False
2028638    False
2028639    False
2028640    False
2028641    False
2028642    False
2028643    False
2028644    False
2028645    False
2028646    False
2028647    False
2028648    False
2028649    False
2028650    False
2028651    False
2028652    False
2028653    False
2028654    False
2028655    False
2028656    False
2028657    False
2028658    False
2028659    False
2028660    False
2028661    False
2028662    False
2028663    False
2028664    False
Name: page_num, Length: 2028665, dtype: bool)' is an invalid key
```

I don't understand really what is happening, because every time I try to change something I get a different ValueError or TypeError or something of the sorts. I'd expect to be able to iterate through the groups yielded by `df.groupby(['file', 'page_num']).groups` and check that my main dataframe `df` has matching values in `label` and `predicted` where `df['file' == group[0]]` and `df['page_num' == group[1]]`.

I'm very new to pandas, so I'm probably missing something minor. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: so you want to sort by file and then by page?

Comment: Seems like you also want to `drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: @Yuca Yes, I want to sort by file and then page. Then compare two separate columns after the fact and do something with the resulting comparison.

Comment: it's unclear on how you handle the fact that you have 3 rows for file1 and page 2. That's why ALollz suggests the dups. What's the logic there? is removing duplicates enough?

Comment: @ALollz Where would I do that? Dropping duplicates in the loop doesn't work, and there will be a lot of duplicates as I expect because the output of the model is a prediction from 0-5 where 0 is the predominant prediction.

Comment: if you're getting a lot of false negatives, the two things your comparing may not be of the same type.. i.e. a comparison of str(2) and float(2) will say false.

Comment: The problem is that the predictions are actually happening at a word-level, so each page might have 50-250 words that each have a `predicted` and a `label`.

Comment: so you want to know your hit ratio of predictions per file per page?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how many in the `predicted` column match the `label` column. I'd also probably like to see which values don't match for further analysis.

Comment: @AnnaNevison I did validate that the types are the same, at least when using the `groupby` function. Each file is of type `str`, and each page_num is of type `int`.

Comment: this should give you a sense of how to start `df1.assign(correct=df1.predicted==df1.label).groupby(['file', 'page_num']).correct.count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `drop_duplicates` you delete the duplicate rows and by `sort_values` ​​you sort first by file name and second by page_num:

```
df.drop_duplicates().sort_values(['file','page_num'],ascending = True)
```

Out:

```
    page_num    file    predicted   label
0           1   file1           0       0
2           2   file1           0       0
5           3   file1           1       1
8           1   file2           0       0
11          2   file2           2       2
```

It is interesting to understand that `df.drop_duplicates().sort_values ​​(['page_num', 'file'], ascending = True)` would not produce the same result since it orders first by `page_num` and then by `file`

Comment: Thanks! I dropped all of the extra columns and then stored the result of this into a new dataframe, and that worked wonderfully with `np.where` to do a lot of my analysis. Thank you again!